# LinearGradient: One pixel vertical line at the right of the Container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Container that I would like to give a 1px vertical line full height in the background to the right. This would look like a right border, but a border is no good, I need the line to be IN the Container, so in case there is a child, it will cover this line- I suppose I have to use a gradient, but don't know how to do it. Most gradient examples are of a percentage of the container and not a pixel measure.

So in the end it would look exactly like a 1px right border when the container is empty, but if it has a child that takes the full width or is aligned to the right, this child covers the line.

Thank you

Edit: I need the equivalent of css

```
background-image: linear-gradient(#000, #000); 
background-size: 1px 100%; 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: center right;
```

Comment: The question isn't too clear. Maybe use a stack to overlap two elements? A gradient doesn't seem the best choice here to me

Comment: Please add an image to display the end result that you want.

Comment: @RaviSinghLodhi I want a vertical line in the background, what in css would be background-image: linear-gradient(#000, #000);
  background-size: 1px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center right;

Comment: @AndreaCostanzo1 I added the css equivalent. Making the two elements overlap is an option, but as last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a foregroundPainter in `CustomPaint` you can paint a line exactly where you want.

```
CustomPaint(
  foregroundPainter: SpecialLinePainter(),
  child: OtherWidget(),
)

...

class SpecialLinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()..color = Color(0xffff0000)
       ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    canvas.drawLine(Offset(size.width, 0), Offset(size.width, size.height), paint);
  }

  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter old) => true;
}
```

Comment: But it would be in the foreground, and not in the background right? Besides, I don't want the canvas size, but the container height. does this paint the container height? I will try it anyways, thank you

Comment: `size` is the size of the `CustomPaint` widget, which will be the same as its child, the container. If you want the line in the background, then use the `painter` property instead of `foregroundPainter`

Comment: I am sorry for my ignorance but I get Missing concrete implementation of 'CustomPainter.shouldRepaint'.  Try implementing the missing method, or make the class abstract.

Comment: Just override it and have it return true. See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter/shouldRepaint.html

Comment: Thank you very much. This is just what I needed.